# datatables sorting by selected checkboxes on top

Tags: datatables

I am trying to order checkboxes in a datatable at the top when they are clicked. This all works fine, but I also need to order them at the top when the page first loads. This I am having a struggle with. Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#schedule-list').DataTable( {
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
            "iDisplayLength": 500,
            columnDefs: [
            { targets: 0, visible: false }
            ],
            orderFixed: [0, 'desc'],
            } );
        $("#schedule-list_wrapper div.toolbar").html('<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm md-btn-flat ml-3 checkall2" type="button" name="CheckAll2" id="checkall2" value="Select All" onClick="this.value=checkScheds(this.form)" style="float:left;">');
        } );


$('#schedule-list').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
   var row =  table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
   table.cell({ row: row.index(), column: 0 } ).data( this.checked ? 1 : 0 )
   row.invalidate().draw()
})

var checkflag2 = false;

function checkScheds() {

  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'schedule' );

  checkflag2 = checkflag2 === false ? true : false;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].checked = checkflag2;
    }

  return checkflag2 === true ? "Deselect All" : "Select All";
}
```

Here is some table data:

```
<table id="schedule-list" class="table table-striped" style="border-style: none; ">
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <cfoutput>
       <cfloop query="qryUserDetail.schedulelist">
          <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td>
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                   <cfif structKeyExists(form, 'schedule') and #ArrayContains(form.schedule,#id#)# or (structKeyExists(url, 'schedule') and #url.schedule# eq #id#)>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input schedule" value="#id#" name="schedule" id="schedule" checked>
                   <cfelse>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input schedule" value="#id#" name="schedule" id="schedule">
                   </cfif>
                   <span class="custom-control-label">#schedname#</span>
                </label>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to provide some more details to help us recreate the problem for ourselves - for example: (a) some sample data (I assume this can be pre-populated in the `<table>`, right?); (b) details for what the `checkScheds()` function is doing.

Comment: Updated and added the rest of the info.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the actual end-result `<table>` data?